# Como resolver este ejercicio en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

¿Alguien puede ayudarme con este ejercicio?:

- Mostrar para cada contrato cantidad total de las comisiones, cantidad a pagar, cantidad pagadas.

La tablas que se nombran en el mismo son:

**Contratos:**
dni,
cuit,
nro_contrato, 
cod_cargo, 
sueldo,
porcentaje_comision,
fecha_incorporacion,
fecha_finalizacion_contrato,
fecha caducidad,
fecha_solicitud

**Comisiones:**
anio_contrato,
mes_contrato,
nro_contrato,
importe_comision,
fecha_pago

Y lo que yo intente hacer parcialmente es:

```
select nro_contrato as 'NUMERO CONTRATO', 
count(*) as 'CANTIDAD TOTAL DE COMISIONES', *************
from comisiones 
group by 1;
```

Pero no logro entender como hacer la parte de las pagadas y a pagar.

Pd: Los ************* es donde no se me ocurre qué poner.

- Si ya ha sido pagado tiene una fecha y si no va a ser nulo el valor de fecha_pago
- La cantidad a pagar implica el numero de comisiones que aun faltan pagar (es decir, si hay 4 comisiones que se tienen que pagar dentro de un mes, quiere decir que hay 4 'cantidades a pagar') y las cantidades pagadas son el numero de comisiones que ya han sido pagadas (si hay 3 comisiones que se pagaron en el dia de ayer, quiere decir que hay 3 'cantidades pagadas')

Comment: ¿Que se almacena en `fecha_pago`? ¿Una fecha si ya ha sido pagado y si no un nulo?

Comment: Exacto! si ya ha sido pagado tiene una fecha y si no va a ser nulo el valor de fecha_pago @Error404

Comment: Hola @Damian. Por favor agrega toda la información relevante en tu pregunta, haciendo click en [edit]

Comment: Ok, ahi lo agrego @Mariano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar una condición dentro de la función `COUNT` para distinguir las comisiones pagadas (con fecha) y no pagadas (sin fecha). En el caso de las no pagadas, pudes usar una expresión `CASE` para filtrar los registros que tienen `fecha_pago` a `null`. Para las pagadas, solo necesitas hacer `count(fecha_pago)`, lo que automáticamente solo cuenta los registros donde `fecha_pago` no es `null`.

```
select nro_contrato,
       count(*) as total,
       count(case when fecha_pago is null then 'X' end) as no_pagadas,
       count(fecha_pago) as pagadas
  from comisiones
 group by nro_contrato
```

Otra opción que puede parecer un poco más sencilla según tu gusto es la de determinar las no pagadas restando las pagadas de la cantidad total:

```
select nro_contrato,
       count(*) as total,
       count(*) - count(fecha_pago) as no_pagadas,
       count(fecha_pago) as pagadas
  from comisiones
 group by nro_contrato
```

Comment: Perfecto! Muchisimas gracias!